# itextsharp: getting total height of table

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

i need to place table2 after the end of table1. i do not know the height of table1. how do i get the height of table1? in vb.net please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `PdfPTable.TotalHeight` property.

I believe it returns the table's height as a float.